# Wix bootstrapper uninstalling MsiPackage instead of updating on update

Tags: wix, upgrade, bootstrapper

My wix bootstrapper is uninstalling my MSIPackage, but not installing the new version in its place. My log files are attached.

Initial log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4QDf83juiMDRVphSnpHdUZLdXM/edit?usp=sharing

Update log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4QDf83juiMDTFRJWk9mWGlEd1U/edit?usp=sharing

I am passing the exact same command line parameters to both the initial install and the update. The variables you see in the logs are also supposed to be being set by these command line parameters, but are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Your log shows your "new" MSI package would be a downgrade:

```
Detected related package: {CC896A91-8808-495D-A755-B05D458DF01D}, scope: PerMachine, version: 6.0.3.0, language: 0 operation: Downgrade
Detected package: Compuweigh, state: Obsolete, cached: None
```

Notice how my log shows it's an upgrade:

```
Detected related package: {EE29FF84-A6FA-4262-879C-EE19C09D20C1}, scope: PerMachine, version: 6.0.0.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
Detected package: StdBAMSI.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
```

I can't tell what the version of your MSI is, but to be safe you should increase the MSI's version when creating a new bundle.

Original answer:

This works for me.  I created a simple bundle using WixStandardBootstrapperApplication with one MSI that has an install condition of "InstallMSI=1".  Log #1 shows the install of version 6.0.0.0.  Log #2 shows the install of version 6.0.0.1.  Log #3 shows the automatic uninstall of version 6.0.0.0 that the 6.0.0.1 bundle kicked off.  (The MSI version was also 6.0.0.0 and 6.0.0.1).

Log #1

```
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:03]i001: Burn v3.9.702.0, Windows v6.1 (Build 7600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\first\Desktop\6.0.0.0\StdBABundle.exe, cmdline: '-burn.unelevated BurnPipe.{435B1658-7BFA-46AB-B5F4-06B7B8D53B92} {EC99137F-1802-4713-8A67-50B10E76D15D} 656 InstallMSI=1'
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:03]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallMSI' to value '1'
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:03]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\first\AppData\Local\Temp\StdBABundle_20140707184903.log'
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:03]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\first\Desktop\6.0.0.0\StdBABundle.exe'
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:03]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\first\Desktop\6.0.0.0\'
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:03]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'StdBABundle'
[0530:074C][2014-07-07T18:49:03]i000: Setting string variable 'InstallMSI' to value '1'
[0530:074C][2014-07-07T18:49:03]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '6.0.0.0'
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:03]i100: Detect begin, 1 packages
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:03]i101: Detected package: StdBAMSI.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:03]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[0530:074C][2014-07-07T18:49:05]i000: Setting numeric variable 'EulaAcceptCheckbox' to value 1
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:05]i200: Plan begin, 1 packages, action: Install
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:05]i052: Condition 'InstallMSI=1' evaluates to true.
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:05]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_StdBAMSI.msi' to value 'C:\Users\first\AppData\Local\Temp\StdBABundle_20140707184903_0_StdBAMSI.msi_rollback.log'
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:05]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_StdBAMSI.msi' to value 'C:\Users\first\AppData\Local\Temp\StdBABundle_20140707184903_0_StdBAMSI.msi.log'
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:05]i201: Planned package: StdBAMSI.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:05]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:05]i300: Apply begin
[0290:0A10][2014-07-07T18:49:05]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\first\AppData\Local\Temp\{fbceb575-7ec8-45a7-9f0a-76bb0896268d}\.be\StdBABundle.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{fbceb575-7ec8-45a7-9f0a-76bb0896268d}\StdBABundle.exe'
[0290:0A10][2014-07-07T18:49:05]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {fbceb575-7ec8-45a7-9f0a-76bb0896268d}, version: 6.0.0.0
[0290:0AE8][2014-07-07T18:49:05]i305: Verified acquired payload: StdBAMSI.msi at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\StdBAMSI.msi, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{EE29FF84-A6FA-4262-879C-EE19C09D20C1}v6.0.0.0\StdBAMSI.msi.
[0290:0A10][2014-07-07T18:49:05]i323: Registering package dependency provider: {EE29FF84-A6FA-4262-879C-EE19C09D20C1}, version: 6.0.0.0, package: StdBAMSI.msi
[0290:0A10][2014-07-07T18:49:05]i301: Applying execute package: StdBAMSI.msi, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{EE29FF84-A6FA-4262-879C-EE19C09D20C1}v6.0.0.0\StdBAMSI.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7"'
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:09]i319: Applied execute package: StdBAMSI.msi, result: 0x0, restart: None
[0290:0A10][2014-07-07T18:49:09]i325: Registering dependency: {fbceb575-7ec8-45a7-9f0a-76bb0896268d} on package provider: {EE29FF84-A6FA-4262-879C-EE19C09D20C1}, package: StdBAMSI.msi
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:09]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x0, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:10]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x0
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:10]i410: Variable: EulaAcceptCheckbox = 1
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:10]i410: Variable: InstallMSI = 1
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:10]i410: Variable: WixBundleAction = 4
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:10]i410: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 1
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:10]i410: Variable: WixBundleFileVersion = 6.0.0.0
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:10]i410: Variable: WixBundleInstalled = 0
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:10]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog = C:\Users\first\AppData\Local\Temp\StdBABundle_20140707184903.log
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:10]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_StdBAMSI.msi = C:\Users\first\AppData\Local\Temp\StdBABundle_20140707184903_0_StdBAMSI.msi.log
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:10]i410: Variable: WixBundleManufacturer = Testing
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:10]i410: Variable: WixBundleName = StdBABundle
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:10]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource = C:\Users\first\Desktop\6.0.0.0\StdBABundle.exe
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:10]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder = C:\Users\first\Desktop\6.0.0.0\
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:10]i410: Variable: WixBundleProviderKey = {fbceb575-7ec8-45a7-9f0a-76bb0896268d}
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:10]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_StdBAMSI.msi = C:\Users\first\AppData\Local\Temp\StdBABundle_20140707184903_0_StdBAMSI.msi_rollback.log
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:10]i410: Variable: WixBundleTag = 
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:10]i410: Variable: WixBundleVersion = 6.0.0.0
[0530:0660][2014-07-07T18:49:10]i007: Exit code: 0x0, restarting: No
```

Log #2

```
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:13]i001: Burn v3.9.702.0, Windows v6.1 (Build 7600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\first\Desktop\6.0.0.1\StdBABundle.exe, cmdline: '-burn.unelevated BurnPipe.{A625785C-EF50-40CB-89C3-E3268C083BBC} {E3D503D5-813C-41E4-82F7-6028A4E78580} 2888 InstallMSI=1'
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:13]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallMSI' to value '1'
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:13]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\first\AppData\Local\Temp\StdBABundle_20140707184913.log'
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:13]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\first\Desktop\6.0.0.1\StdBABundle.exe'
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:13]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\first\Desktop\6.0.0.1\'
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:13]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'StdBABundle'
[0128:0700][2014-07-07T18:49:13]i000: Setting string variable 'InstallMSI' to value '1'
[0128:0700][2014-07-07T18:49:13]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '6.0.0.1'
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:13]i100: Detect begin, 1 packages
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:13]i102: Detected related bundle: {fbceb575-7ec8-45a7-9f0a-76bb0896268d}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 6.0.0.0, operation: MajorUpgrade
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:13]i103: Detected related package: {EE29FF84-A6FA-4262-879C-EE19C09D20C1}, scope: PerMachine, version: 6.0.0.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:13]i101: Detected package: StdBAMSI.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:13]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[0128:0700][2014-07-07T18:49:15]i000: Setting numeric variable 'EulaAcceptCheckbox' to value 1
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:15]i200: Plan begin, 1 packages, action: Install
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:15]i052: Condition 'InstallMSI=1' evaluates to true.
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:15]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_StdBAMSI.msi' to value 'C:\Users\first\AppData\Local\Temp\StdBABundle_20140707184913_0_StdBAMSI.msi_rollback.log'
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:15]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_StdBAMSI.msi' to value 'C:\Users\first\AppData\Local\Temp\StdBABundle_20140707184913_0_StdBAMSI.msi.log'
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:15]i201: Planned package: StdBAMSI.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:15]i207: Planned related bundle: {fbceb575-7ec8-45a7-9f0a-76bb0896268d}, type: Upgrade, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: Uninstall, rollback: Install, dependency: None
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:15]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:15]i300: Apply begin
[0B48:0BB8][2014-07-07T18:49:15]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\first\AppData\Local\Temp\{d3fbb446-cb6c-464e-850c-c703ddebcf26}\.be\StdBABundle.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{d3fbb446-cb6c-464e-850c-c703ddebcf26}\StdBABundle.exe'
[0B48:0BB8][2014-07-07T18:49:15]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {d3fbb446-cb6c-464e-850c-c703ddebcf26}, version: 6.0.0.1
[0B48:033C][2014-07-07T18:49:15]i305: Verified acquired payload: StdBAMSI.msi at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\StdBAMSI.msi, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{5A22F992-3461-42E1-98AF-32DCA58F228B}v6.0.0.1\StdBAMSI.msi.
[0B48:0BB8][2014-07-07T18:49:15]i323: Registering package dependency provider: {5A22F992-3461-42E1-98AF-32DCA58F228B}, version: 6.0.0.1, package: StdBAMSI.msi
[0B48:0BB8][2014-07-07T18:49:15]i301: Applying execute package: StdBAMSI.msi, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{5A22F992-3461-42E1-98AF-32DCA58F228B}v6.0.0.1\StdBAMSI.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7"'
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:21]i319: Applied execute package: StdBAMSI.msi, result: 0x0, restart: None
[0B48:0BB8][2014-07-07T18:49:21]i325: Registering dependency: {d3fbb446-cb6c-464e-850c-c703ddebcf26} on package provider: {5A22F992-3461-42E1-98AF-32DCA58F228B}, package: StdBAMSI.msi
[0B48:0BB8][2014-07-07T18:49:21]i301: Applying execute package: {fbceb575-7ec8-45a7-9f0a-76bb0896268d}, action: Uninstall, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{fbceb575-7ec8-45a7-9f0a-76bb0896268d}\StdBABundle.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{fbceb575-7ec8-45a7-9f0a-76bb0896268d}\StdBABundle.exe" -uninstall -quiet -burn.related.upgrade -burn.ancestors={d3fbb446-cb6c-464e-850c-c703ddebcf26}'
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:27]i319: Applied execute package: {fbceb575-7ec8-45a7-9f0a-76bb0896268d}, result: 0x0, restart: None
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:27]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x0, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:29]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x0
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:29]i410: Variable: EulaAcceptCheckbox = 1
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:29]i410: Variable: InstallMSI = 1
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:29]i410: Variable: WixBundleAction = 4
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:29]i410: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 1
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:29]i410: Variable: WixBundleFileVersion = 6.0.0.1
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:29]i410: Variable: WixBundleInstalled = 0
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:29]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog = C:\Users\first\AppData\Local\Temp\StdBABundle_20140707184913.log
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:29]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_StdBAMSI.msi = C:\Users\first\AppData\Local\Temp\StdBABundle_20140707184913_0_StdBAMSI.msi.log
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:29]i410: Variable: WixBundleManufacturer = Testing
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:29]i410: Variable: WixBundleName = StdBABundle
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:29]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource = C:\Users\first\Desktop\6.0.0.1\StdBABundle.exe
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:29]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder = C:\Users\first\Desktop\6.0.0.1\
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:29]i410: Variable: WixBundleProviderKey = {d3fbb446-cb6c-464e-850c-c703ddebcf26}
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:29]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_StdBAMSI.msi = C:\Users\first\AppData\Local\Temp\StdBABundle_20140707184913_0_StdBAMSI.msi_rollback.log
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:29]i410: Variable: WixBundleTag = 
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:29]i410: Variable: WixBundleVersion = 6.0.0.1
[0128:01B4][2014-07-07T18:49:29]i007: Exit code: 0x0, restarting: No
```

Log #3

```
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:21]i001: Burn v3.9.702.0, Windows v6.1 (Build 7600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{fbceb575-7ec8-45a7-9f0a-76bb0896268d}\StdBABundle.exe, cmdline: '-burn.unelevated BurnPipe.{CB8148FB-6B2A-497A-A9B4-A2A7F6C513BB} {A9092EAE-4EC3-4BB1-BB5A-E981642EC3D1} 2492 -uninstall -quiet -burn.related.upgrade -burn.ancestors={d3fbb446-cb6c-464e-850c-c703ddebcf26} -burn.embedded BurnPipe.{35DE7EEF-D3ED-40B0-9D33-D3F98FAD4523} {30D2EEBD-1531-4014-B3C9-9E6170CDFA30} 2888'
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:21]i003: This bundle is being run by a related bundle as type 'Upgrade'.
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:21]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallMSI' to value '1'
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:21]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\first\AppData\Local\Temp\StdBABundle_20140707184921.log'
[0770:0BE0][2014-07-07T18:49:21]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '6.0.0.0'
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:21]i100: Detect begin, 1 packages
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:21]i102: Detected related bundle: {d3fbb446-cb6c-464e-850c-c703ddebcf26}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 6.0.0.1, operation: None
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:21]i103: Detected related package: {5A22F992-3461-42E1-98AF-32DCA58F228B}, scope: PerMachine, version: 6.0.0.1, language: 0 operation: None
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:21]i101: Detected package: StdBAMSI.msi, state: Present, cached: Complete
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:21]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:21]i200: Plan begin, 1 packages, action: Uninstall
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:21]i214: Plan skipped related bundle: {d3fbb446-cb6c-464e-850c-c703ddebcf26}, type: Upgrade, because it was previously scheduled.
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:21]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_StdBAMSI.msi' to value 'C:\Users\first\AppData\Local\Temp\StdBABundle_20140707184921_0_StdBAMSI.msi_rollback.log'
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:21]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_StdBAMSI.msi' to value 'C:\Users\first\AppData\Local\Temp\StdBABundle_20140707184921_0_StdBAMSI.msi.log'
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:21]i207: Planned related bundle: {d3fbb446-cb6c-464e-850c-c703ddebcf26}, type: Upgrade, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, dependency: None
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:21]i201: Planned package: StdBAMSI.msi, state: Present, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: Uninstall, rollback: Install, cache: No, uncache: Yes, dependency: Unregister
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:21]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:21]i300: Apply begin
[09BC:0810][2014-07-07T18:49:21]i326: Removed dependency: {fbceb575-7ec8-45a7-9f0a-76bb0896268d} on package provider: {EE29FF84-A6FA-4262-879C-EE19C09D20C1}, package StdBAMSI.msi
[09BC:0810][2014-07-07T18:49:21]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {EE29FF84-A6FA-4262-879C-EE19C09D20C1}, package: StdBAMSI.msi
[09BC:0810][2014-07-07T18:49:21]i301: Applying execute package: StdBAMSI.msi, action: Uninstall, path: (null), arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7"'
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:27]i319: Applied execute package: StdBAMSI.msi, result: 0x0, restart: None
[09BC:0810][2014-07-07T18:49:27]i351: Removing cached package: StdBAMSI.msi, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{EE29FF84-A6FA-4262-879C-EE19C09D20C1}v6.0.0.0\
[09BC:0810][2014-07-07T18:49:27]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {fbceb575-7ec8-45a7-9f0a-76bb0896268d}
[09BC:0810][2014-07-07T18:49:27]i352: Removing cached bundle: {fbceb575-7ec8-45a7-9f0a-76bb0896268d}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{fbceb575-7ec8-45a7-9f0a-76bb0896268d}\
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:27]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x0, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:27]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x0
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:27]i410: Variable: InstallMSI = 1
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:27]i410: Variable: WixBundleAction = 3
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:27]i410: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 1
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:27]i410: Variable: WixBundleFileVersion = 6.0.0.0
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:27]i410: Variable: WixBundleInstalled = 1
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:27]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog = C:\Users\first\AppData\Local\Temp\StdBABundle_20140707184921.log
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:27]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_StdBAMSI.msi = C:\Users\first\AppData\Local\Temp\StdBABundle_20140707184921_0_StdBAMSI.msi.log
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:27]i410: Variable: WixBundleManufacturer = Testing
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:27]i410: Variable: WixBundleName = StdBABundle
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:27]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource = C:\Users\first\Desktop\6.0.0.0\StdBABundle.exe
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:27]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder = C:\Users\first\Desktop\6.0.0.0\
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:27]i410: Variable: WixBundleProviderKey = {fbceb575-7ec8-45a7-9f0a-76bb0896268d}
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:27]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_StdBAMSI.msi = C:\Users\first\AppData\Local\Temp\StdBABundle_20140707184921_0_StdBAMSI.msi_rollback.log
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:27]i410: Variable: WixBundleTag = 
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:27]i410: Variable: WixBundleVersion = 6.0.0.0
[0770:01A4][2014-07-07T18:49:27]i007: Exit code: 0x0, restarting: No
```

Comment: When I perform this upgrade, I get the following logs: Log2? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4QDf83juiMDX3RUSkRuek9Qcm8/edit?usp=sharing                 log3? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4QDf83juiMDaFhKSFFybG5ONDg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @downeysyndrome Not sure what the first log was supposed to be, but the second did show what was wrong.

Comment: What was wrong? I am sort of new to Wix and trying to figure this whole thing out..

Comment: @downeysyndrome I edited my answer, it's at the top.

Comment: I do not understand why it would be a downgrade. the new version number is a higher version than the previous one.

Comment: @downeysyndrome Have you tried installing (and then upgrading) your MSI by itself, outside of the bootstrapper?  Does that work?  Also, look at the Upgrade table in the MSI (Upgrade/MajorUpgrade element in WiX) because that's how Windows and Burn decide whether it's an upgrade.

Comment: It was the way I had my upgrade table set up. Everything is working better now. I can't, however, seem to perform a downgrade via the bootstrapper, even though I have MajorUpgrade AllowDowngrades=yes in my MSI. Is there anything I can do to do this?

Comment: @downeysyndrome If that's possible today, it would be with a custom BootstrapperApplication.  That's really a separate question.